# Can more than 2 variables be auto-filled in a VSCode snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I have a code snippet in VSCode with the following body...

`"<span data-link=\"${2:$1}\" title=\"“${3:$2}”\">${1:$CLIPBOARD}</span>$0"`

when it expands, the clipboard contents goes into `$1` & `$2`, but `$3` always shows up empty. If I change `$1` to something other than the clipboard, or if I "Paste", it affects all 3. From the documentation, it seems I should be able to just `tab`, `tab`, `tab` and the result be that all 3 are what was in the clipboard, but that's not the case, the 3rd one would be empty.

Is there a bug in my snippet? in VSCode? or is this expected behavior?

Comment: what if you use `${3:$1}`, why not `${2:$CLIPBOARD}` and `${3:$CLIPBOARD}`

Comment: if I change $1 or $2 I'd like that to be reflected in $3 as well... 2 & 3 are titles of entries in a Dictionary, but the difference is that if $2 has a comma I remove it in $3. e.g.: `data-link="Way, the" title="“The Way”"` $1 sometimes matches & other times is completely different.  What I usually do is cut the text to the clipboard & invoke the snippet in its place, wrapping the text with the `<span>`

Comment: in other words... for the 50% of the time they're not all the same, $1 is the different one while 2 & 3 are either identical, or the comma thing is the only difference